# how to use 'if' binding in knockout.js to exclude/include items from dependent drop-down menus

Tags: knockout.js

I've got 2 vehicle drop-down menus - Cars1: {Toyota, Mazda, Ford, Honda} and Cars2: {Porsche, Maybach, Ferrari, Maserati}.

I'm trying to use the 'if-binding' in knockout.js so that if 'Toyota' is selected from the first drop-down list, only 'Porsche' and 'Maybach' is shown from the 2nd drop-down.  However, if 'Mazda' or 'Honda' is selected from the first drop-down menu then everything is able to be selected from the 2nd drop-down menu.

I've come up with this but it doesn't seem to work:

```
<!-- ko if: Cars1() === $root.Constants.Cars1.Toyota === $root.Constants.Cars1.Porsche && $root.Constants.Cars1.Maybach -->
<-- drop-down menu: Cars2 /drop-down menu-->
<!-- /ko -->

<!-- ko if: Cars1() === $root.Constants.Cars1.Mazda || $root.Constants.Cars1.Honda  -->
<-- drop-down menu: Cars2 /drop-down menu-->
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: How does it not seem to work: crash, freeze, error messages, unexpected behavior, locusts?

Answer (score 1):

You should test those `if` statements in your console to fid out what's going on.

```js
console.log(
  "Toyota"  === "Toyota" === "Porsche" && "Maybach", // false
  "Porche"  === "Toyota" === "Porsche" && "Maybach", // false
  "Maybach" === "Toyota" === "Porsche" && "Maybach", // false
  "Mazda"   === "Toyota" === "Porsche" && "Maybach", // false
  "Honda"   === "Toyota" === "Porsche" && "Maybach", // false

  // What happens:
  (("Toyota"  === "Toyota") === "Porsche") && "Maybach",
  true === "Porsche" && "Maybach"

  // I.e.: it can never be `true` or `Maybach`, 
  // because `true` nor `false` equals `Porsche`
);

console.log(
  "Toyota"  === "Mazda" || "Honda", // "Honda"
  "Porche"  === "Mazda" || "Honda", // "Honda"
  "Maybach" === "Mazda" || "Honda", // "Honda"
  "Mazda"   === "Mazda" || "Honda", //  true
  "Honda"   === "Mazda" || "Honda", // "Honda",

   // Whenever the input does not equal `Mazda`, 
   // `Honda` is returned which the `if` bindind sees as a `true` value.
   // (Unless the constant's value is `0`, `null`, `undefined`, etc.)
);
```

Once you got this figured out, I'd advice you to move the bindings' logic to your viewmodels:

```js
const cars = [ "Toyota", "Porsche", "Maybach", "Mazda", "Honda" ];
const selectedCar = ko.observable("Toyota");
const dropDown2 = ko.pureComputed(() => {
  switch (selectedCar()) {
    case "Toyota":
    case "Porsche":
    case "Maybach":
      return [ "TPM1", "TPM2", "etc." ];
    case "Mazda":
    case "Honda":
      return [ "HM1", "HM2", "etc." ];
    default: return [];
  }
});
  

ko.applyBindings({ cars, selectedCar, dropDown2 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<select data-bind="options: cars, value: selectedCar"></select>
<select data-bind="options: dropDown2"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is not a ideal scenario to use knockout if bindings. 

Ideally, what to show in "cars2" dropdown should be decided by a callback function in Javascript as below:

```js
var VM = function(){
    var self=this;
    self.cars1 = ko.observableArray(["Toyota", "Mazda", "Ford", "Honda"]); 
    self.cars2 = ko.observableArray(["Porsche", "Maybach", "Ferrari", "Maserati"]);
    self.selectedCar = ko.observable("Ford");
    
    self.selectedCar.subscribe(function(product) {        
        if(self.selectedCar() === "Toyota"){
            self.cars2(["Porsche", "Maybach"]);
        }else{
            self.cars2(["Porsche", "Maybach", "Ferrari", "Maserati"]);
        }
    });
}

ko.applyBindings(new VM());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<select data-bind="options: cars1, value: selectedCar"></select>
<select data-bind="options: cars2"></select>
```

However, if you are hell bent on using knockout if bindings, here you go:

```js
var VM = function(){
    var self=this;
    self.cars1 = ko.observableArray(["Toyota", "Mazda", "Ford", "Honda"]); 
    self.cars11 = ko.observableArray(["Porsche", "Maybach"]);
    self.cars12 = ko.observableArray(["Porsche", "Maybach", "Ferrari", "Maserati"]);
    self.selectedCar = ko.observable("Ford"); 
    
}

ko.applyBindings(new VM());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<select data-bind="options: cars1, value: selectedCar"></select>

  <!-- ko if: (selectedCar()=="Toyota") -->
    <select data-bind="options: cars11"></select>
  <!-- /ko -->
  
  <!-- ko if: !(selectedCar()=="Toyota") -->
    <select data-bind="options: cars12"></select>
  <!-- /ko -->
```